# What should I do to add the shortcut keys in Web Application and Web Sites?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mongodb, sass

Can someone explain me how do I create a shortcut key (for e.g. Alt+S = Share) in my Web Application?

I am using HTML + SCSS + JS + MongoDB + React

I know this is super open end question but if someone can explain me how to do it then I add all shortcut combinations I want in my Web App

Million thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on keyboard events https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

from the docs:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  const keyName = event.key;

  if (keyName === 'Control') {
    // do not alert when only Control key is pressed.
    return;
  }

  if (event.ctrlKey) {
    // Even though event.key is not 'Control' (e.g., 'a' is pressed),
    // event.ctrlKey may be true if Ctrl key is pressed at the same time.
    alert(`Combination of ctrlKey + ${keyName}`);
  } else {
    alert(`Key pressed ${keyName}`);
  }
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  const keyName = event.key;

  // As the user releases the Ctrl key, the key is no longer active,
  // so event.ctrlKey is false.
  if (keyName === 'Control') {
    alert('Control key was released');
  }
}, false);
```